# Searching semantically for symbols in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, symbology, layouts

Sorry for the noob question, but is there any resource (on the web) where I could more or less search semantically for symbols to use in an ArcMap layout?

Using the *Symbol Selector*, I have to scroll through all the symbols from different *Style References*. I assume there might be one which is fitting my purpose, so is there a more intelligent way of finding it?

(Current case: have to add some measurement towers to a map.)

Comment: There are also a number of fonts (that all start with ESRI...) that you can use as character marker symbols. Not sure all of them are referenced in a style. I usually find what I need there, but it takes some time to go through them all.

Comment: Is using 10.0 mandatory for you?  Upgrading to 10.1 would have given you a search toolbar for symbols by name and keywords right there on the Symbol Selector.

Comment: I can't check, but I think that the feature that you mention is already available for ArcGIS 10.0 http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/28/symbols-and-styles-in-arcgis-10-0/

Comment: The search feature is available, though as far as I can see it only works on symbol names (still have to figure out if symbols even have keywords). I was thinking of a more semantical search, probably user-backed by tagging of the available symbols. Like searching for "cat", and getting both something named "kitten" (and maybe a symbol for bulldozer at the same time. ;-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @radouxju the search for symbols functionality was introduced at ArcGIS 10.0 and from a blog enitled [Symbols and styles in ArcGIS 10.0](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/09/28/symbols-and-styles-in-arcgis-10-0/):

> Finding appropriate symbols to apply to your features and graphics is
>   easy in ArcGIS 10 because you can search for and use symbols without
>   having to know to which style they belong, nor have that style
>   referenced. When searching for symbols, you can search within all
>   styles available on your system—including your custom styles—or you
>   can limit search results to only those styles currently referenced.
>
> Symbols in ArcGIS 10 have searchable tags that describe graphic
>   characteristics, such color or type. These tags can be modified for
>   symbols in custom styles to describe any relevant characteristic, such
>   as a related project, map, layer, scale, or specification.

It sounds to me like the type of search you are looking for is available for custom styles - you just need to add the tags you want to search for - but not for styles that come with ArcGIS Desktop which you can only search for using graphic characteristics.